# In SQL, filter IDs with only one value in other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say we have a table with 2 columns in a SQL Server table `MyTable`:

| ID | rank |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | s |
| 1 | w |
| 2 | s |
| 2 | s |
| 3 | w |
| .. | .. |

How to find all IDs which have only have value `'s'` in the rank column, and no other ranks?

I expect the result to be

| ID | rank |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | s |

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. Also, your table has _columns_, not fields.

Comment: `HAVING count(distinct rank) = 1`, if you want id having only one distinct rank value, s or other. `HAVING count(case when rank <> 's' then 1 end) = 0` to find id's having only s ranks.

Comment: @FrancoisDuCoq It would be good if you show what you have tried when asking your next question

Comment: Just as a side note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **completely unsupported** (out of even extended support) by now - and have been for several years. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `group by` and `having` clauses :

The total count of each ID with `rank='s'` should match the total count of all rows.

```
SELECT ID --, 's' as rank
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING count(CASE WHEN rank = 's' THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/CY5gag7V)

Comment: Or `HAVING count(case when rank <> 's' then 1 end) = 0` as mentioned in comments

Comment: It works only if column rank doesn’t contains null values https://dbfiddle.uk/J6h5CAYv

Comment: Then could use `IS DISTINCT FROM` https://dbfiddle.uk/ORJZS60a alternatively `OR rank IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

[Just one more solution uses `NOT EXISTS` condition](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/6be213f4f3dcdf9b9a63ad4d4ac86be7/):

```
select distinct * from mytable
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable mytable_copy where rank <> 's' and mytable_copy.ID = mytable.ID
);
```